# Подогнать слайдер на сайте WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть тестовый [сайт](http://n988692e.bget.ru/), на котором установлена CMS WordPress и тема Onetake. Установил слайдер Easing Slider во вторую секцию на главную страницу, задал в настройках слайдера ширину 1350 и высоту 760, и поставил галочку на параметр Enable 100% full width.

Проблема в том, что в браузере Firefox на картинку наезжает третья секция, но в опере и хроме все хорошо отображается. Почему так происходит, и как это исправить?
В мозиле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня ваш сайт выглядит одинаково в файрфоксе и гугл хроме. Выделите, пожалуйста, на скриншоте проблемную область

Comment: Может это у меня браузер не корректно работает?

Comment: Браузер работает, дело не в нём, а в размере области просмотра

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае всё зависит от размеров окна браузера, в котором вы смотрите сайт, а не от типа обозревателя. Для всех изображений слайдера у вас установлено правило, принудительно растягивающее изображение на всю ширину блока, высота которого всегда равна 760px:

```
.easingslider-image {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Т. к. размеры изображения увеличиваются пропорционально, меняется и его высота, которая обрезается в случае, если превышает 760px.
Так что третья секция тут не причём, необходимо настраивать и стилизовать слайдер.

Проверить очень просто: сверните браузер и обновите страницу. Меняйте размеры окна и увидите как меняется вид изображений.

Comment: В хроме и мозиле вроде один размер окна, разве нет? Честно говоря я вообще без понятия как сделать настройку и стилизацию слайдера, знаю только основы верстки. Может Вы дадите мне ссылку на какую нибудь статью, или несколько, которые помогут решить возникшую проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насчет Wordpress но когда занимался версткой,и когда специально писал для Firefox для css тегов использовал приставку -moz- .Возможно вам нужно где-то в коде этого слайдера , в css добавить свойства определённые именно для Firefox.

Comment: Мне, что сейчас надо скопировать нынешние стили и везде написать например,  {width-moz-: 100%;} , то есть везде добавить -moz- ?  Я не очень силен верстке.